# Display data once if same

Tags: php, mysql

With this code:

```
    $query = "select users.id_user, users.full_name, users.rights, users.group, group.id, group.name
     from users
        inner join group
            on users.group=group.id
                    where users.rights= 2";

    // connection code

    while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($res))

    {
            $id_user = $re["id_user"];
            $id_group = $re["id"];
            $full_name= $re["full_name"]; 
            $group_name= $re["name"];

        echo "<div>";
        echo "<p><strong>$group_name</strong></p>";
        echo "$full_name<br />";
        echo "</div>";  
    }

    ?>
```

I get this:

**Group1**
User1

**Group1**
User2

**Group2**
User3

**Group2**
User4

and I need it like this:

**Group1**
User1
User2

**Group2**
User3
User4

How to show group name just once?

Comment: Within your loop, keep track of the last group name seen and compare the current record with that; then adjust your output accordingly.

Comment: Do as @eggyal suggests, but also add `ORDER BY group.name, user.full_name` to the end of your query (this assumes that `User1`, `User2`, etc. is `user.full_name`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak your query that you use the database power to give you the information you need.

```
select 
   usergroup.name 
 , GROUP_CONCAT(user.name SEPARATOR '<br />') 'users'

from 
 user

inner join 
 usergroup

on
 user.usergroup_id = usergroup.id

where 
 user.rights = 2

group by 
  usergroup.id
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d104/1 in your php you can use $row['users']

Comment: SQL shouldn't be used for data presentation, that's not what it's for.

Comment: matter of taste but SQL (Structured Query Language) is a special-purpose programming language designed for managing data held in a relational database management system (RDBMS). Originally based upon relational algebra and tuple relational calculus, SQL consists of a data definition language and a data manipulation language... i think i manipulate data here or not????

Comment: No, you manipulate the way data is displayed, not what data is returned from the db, that's a totally diffrent thing. You can look up MVC for example to see how it should be seperated.

Comment: True your are right for about 80% +! MVC could be used for this but this is better with memory usage and CPU because PHP doenst have have an extra run to manipulate the data. and GROUP_CONCAT isn't really database portable if you want portable SQL code you should indeed handle this in your View

Comment: There's really no chance to check if it's better memory usage or not but either way it's premature optimalization at best.

Answer (score 0):

You may use associative arrays for this task. For example, make an array $groups, and in your while loop do something like

```
    $groups[$re["name"]]["full_name"][] = $re["full_name"];
```

Then, when you display your html loop through $groups and inside it loop though full names.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
$query = "SELECT users.id_user, users.full_name, users.rights, users.group, group.id, group.name
         FROM users
         INNER JOIN group
         ON users.group=group.id
         WHERE users.rights=2
         ORDER BY group.name ASC";

// connection code

$group_name = '';

while ($re = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    if( $group_name === '' )
    {
        $group_name = $re["name"];
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<p><strong>$group_name</strong></p>";
    }
    elseif( $group_name !== $re["name"] )
    {
        $group_name = $re["name"];
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<p><strong>$group_name</strong></p>";
    }

    $id_user = $re["id_user"];
    $id_group = $re["id"];
    $full_name= $re["full_name"]; 

    echo "$full_name<br />";

}

?>
```

It's basically ordering the result by the group names, and while it iterates, the group name is being checked. If it's the same, only the name is printed, if it differs, the div is closed, a new one is made and the new group title is echoed.